# ASP.NET web application deployment

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I need a good tutorial to set up Windows Server 2008 with IIS 6.1 to install an ASP.NET web application built on .NET 4.0. I want to host it publicly. Can anyone recommend me a good site which outlines all the required configuration steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deployed the web application myself. 
First I created a setup file for the application. Installed it in the server and added a new web site in the IIS with its virtual directory pointed at the installed path. Application pool was set specifically to .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a little googling, and it appears that you can install the IIS 6.0 management tools and FTP on 2008, but not the web server itself (i.e., you can't serve web pages up from anything other than IIS 7).

This thread ([Thread: Windows Server 2008 with IIS 6.0](http://forums.iis.net/t/1150249.aspx)) indicates that you can run sites under an application pool that is using Classic Mode to get close to IIS 6:

"You can't install IIS 6 on w2k8.  You can configure your application pool to use Classic Mode, this runs the traditional items like ASP.NET as ISAPI-Filters like they do in IIS 6.   That is as close to IIS 6 you'll get, which is darn close in my experience, things that don't work on iis 7 integrated mode work in Classic Mode.  Hope that helps." (From the above linked thread).

This thread ([Managing IIS 6.0 Servers from Windows Vista (and other Management Stuff)](http://blogs.iis.net/chrisad/archive/2007/01/03/managing-iis-6-0-servers-from-windows-vista-and-other-management-stuff.aspx)) is about Vista with IIS 6 and 7, but goes into a little more detail about the web management tools.

Comment: Thanks for the note Tim. However I have already deployed the site using IIS 6.1 with AppFabric for monitoring WCF services.